# Remove default wordpress roles

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles

I'm creating a custom plugin that will add some custom roles to the standard one of wordpress. The roles are added without problems to wp, but I have some doubt. Can I remove the default roles of wp and leave only the admin one and the custom roles I've created?

I need to have a role where the user that is assigned to it can edit other users and one that will need only to read his profile informations. Are all the options for these two roles required or I can pass only the capabilities I want to give to the roles instead of passing the value for all available options?

Comment: have you considered hiding the roles instead? Even if you remove them you'll need to migrate your users over to the new roles or they won't be able to do anything on the site, and the same is true when your plugin is deactivated or gets updated. Likewise some scenarios don't load plugins, e.g. parameters on WP CLI commands let you skip loading plugins and themes, and this could be something that breaks things for your host if it's a managed WP host

Comment: Not considered to hide roles, how I can achive this? And, about the params that the `add:role()` accept, can I skip all the fields I don't need and consider them automatically false?